# Hashing a hard disk to check for zeroes

Tags: performance, hash, compare, hard-drive

I am working on a little piece of software which checks a hard disk for zeroes. the problem I am having is that this will take hours to if I have to check every single byte. wouldn't it be possible to do something with hashing? I could hash the hard disk but how would I go about verifying that the hash is indeed saying it is all zeroes?

Comment: What do you mean "check a harddisk for zeros"? Please describe in more detail what you're trying to do so my answer can contain more than "no, that won't work because ...".

Comment: If you want to generate a hash of the content of your harddisk, you would have to go through each byte of your harddisk to generate that hash. So that doesn't help you. If you need to check for zeros, you need to check each byte.

Comment: check if every byte on a harddisk is zero. I hoped hashing wouldnt have to check every byte...